php composer use function and call in required files doesn't work
I'm trying to declare the JWT classes in a separate file to use them in functions, but it's not working, and I really don't understand why.
If I put the use declarations from use.php into jwt.php, it works fine, but I want to be able to put them elsewhere or at least understand why it doesn't work.
I have the error message :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "JWT" not found in
/var/www/config/includes/functions/jwt.php:4

I have created a minimal sandbox reproducing the structure of my project. Thank you for your help!
Here is the sandbox : https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/tromp?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

use declarations aren't things that you can simply separate into a different file. They are mechanisms that exist to tell PHP about which classes you mean when you're accessing them across different namespaces. If you're looking to simplify the the names of your class calls, consider wrapping your classes either with a globally accessible function, Facade Pattern, or a Proxy Pattern to achieve what you want.

Are you sure this problem is related to Composer in any way? Also, why is this tagged with [tag:require], while you should not manually require any files when using any autoloader?

Without the use declarations, JWT in the jwt.php is an unqualified class name, which means that the class will be resolved under the current namespace (which is global, as this file does not declare any namespace) instead of Firebase\JWT\JWT. Therefore it's not surprising that PHP cannot find class JWT. If you don't want to use the use declarations, you must write a qualified name (Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode) in that file.
